# Is there a way to speed up react native's project initialization?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native, and having some trouble setting up projects. Whenever I run react-native init , the prompt gets stuck on "Installing react-native package from npm" for hours, literally. My net speed's decent but this npm process tends to take quite a lot of time. Have been working on Node+React for a while but haven't encountered something of this sort. Tried it multiple times. Similar issues have been reported by users but none of their hacks seem to be working out for me. So...is there any way to accelerate this?

Thinking of resorting to some means of offline installation of npm packages.

Also, adding '--verbose' gives an error message as follows[image]

Node version - 4.4.5

NPM version  - 2.15.5